# casperjs: can I use node packages inside casperjs with 'require' keyword?

Tags: node.js, casperjs

I do use casperjs.
I need to use some ready to go node packagages with casperjs such as: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-write-stream to create CSV files

inside my capserjs file I have:

```
var fs = require('fs'); // this works
var system = require('system'); // this works
var csvWriter = require('csv-write-stream'); // stops the script, no error, it  works fine with nodejs script
var writer = csvWriter()
```

It looks like some require are ok (system, fs), but not 'csv-write-stream'

I would like to understand if (I can/how I can) use require packages in casperjs ?

I found that:

> CasperJS allows using nodejs modules installed through npm. Note that
>   since CasperJS uses it’s own JavaScript environment, npm modules that
>   use node-specific features will not work under CasperJS.

So how to determine which module will work ?

Comment: Some works some fail for others. The only way to really know is to test

Comment: is there a repository for "working" packages ?

Comment: Both `fs` and `system` are PhantomJS' built-in modules. They have nothing to do with node.js.

Answer (score 1):

From official [documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/writing_modules.html):

> CasperJS **allows** using nodejs modules installed through npm. Note that
>   since CasperJS uses it’s own JavaScript environment, npm modules that
>   use **node-specific** features will not work under CasperJS.

So, you can try any node module which you want to import and test it works or not...

As Artjom B pointed out, `fs` and `system` are phantomjs modules. And all phantomjs module is listed [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/).